# Websphere classloader issue - throws classNotFound exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, ear, websphere-8

I am using WebSphere Application Server v8.5. Currently we are manually adding all the dependency jar to manifest.mf manually. Is there a way by websphere to pic all jar exist in AppInf/Lib folder? with out adding manually.

Answer (score 2):

By default, any jars contained in a /lib directory within your EAR will be added to the application class loader's class path.  That location can be changed by using the "library-directory" attribute in application.xml as described in [this article](http://mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-deploy/how-do-i-change-the-default-lib-directory-in-an-ear-file)).

You could also create a shared library and associate it with the application - a directory entry used as a shared library class path will pull in all the jar files in that directory.